# Asyncio combined with custom modules and aiohttp

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-module, aiohttp

I am trying to sleep a module for a couple seconds, while sleeping, the script should continue running.
When the sleep is over, the module should put `data["found"] = True`, but the code never reaches past `asyncio.sleep()`
The code should print:

- **"bulbasaur"**
- **"do stuff"** *x 5*
- **"bulbasaur"**

But bulbasaur never comes back.

**main.py:**

```
# main.py
urls = {"pokemon": pokemon.data, "nba": nba.data}

async def get_data(session, url):
    async with session.get(url, headers=headers) as r:
        return await r.json()


async def execute_modules(data):
    if pokemon.data["found"]:
        asyncio.create_task(nba.find_name(data[0]))
    else:
        asyncio.create_task(pokemon.find_name(data[0]))
        asyncio.create_task(nba.find_name(data[1]))


async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for key, value in urls.items():
            if not value["found"]:
                tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(get_data(session, value["url"])))

        data = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        # print(data[1])
        await execute_modules(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        asyncio.run(main())
        time.sleep(2)
```

**pokemon.py:**

```
import asyncio

data = {
    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1",
    "found": False
}


async def find_name(pokemon):
    if pokemon["name"] == "bulbasaur":
        data["found"] = True
        print("bulbasaur found")
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        data["found"] = False
    else:
        print("no bulbasaur")
```

**nba.py**

```
data = {
    "url": "https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players/1",
    "found": False
}

async def find_name(nba):
    print("do stuff")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies in `execute_models()`. There you spawn 1-2 tasks but never wait for them to complete.

This means that the task is scheduled to run the next event loop iteration but there never comes another event loop iteration since you never `await` anything after spawning the task. So `main()` exits and `asyncio.run()` cancels all tasks left. What you need to do is use `asyncio.gather()` inside `execute_models()` or have `execute_models()` return the tasks it creates and put another `asyncio.gather()` inside `main()`.

```py
async def execute_modules(data):
    tasks = []
    if pokemon.data["found"]:
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(nba.find_name(data[0])))
    else:
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(pokemon.find_name(data[0])))
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(nba.find_name(data[1])))
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

---

Since it seems like you want the script to continue running and not wait for the sleep, you may want to put the `while True` loop inside `main()` and change `time.sleep(2)` to `asyncio.sleep(2)` instead of what I proposed above.

The important aspect here is that the event loop is kept alive so that the tasks aren't cancelled and continue to run.

Comment: the solution in the second paragraph did the trick, i put the while loop in the main and changed time.sleep to asyncio.sleep.